# FFmpeg RTSP to mp4 recording speed raises to x60 when camera microphone is ON

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, stream, camera, rtsp

I'm working with some kind of recorder that uses FFmpeg to capture RTSP stream from various IP cameras. It used to work fine on every camera I tried. That were cameras from various manufacturers, but the configuration was pretty the same.
`1080p, ~10 fps, H.264, ~12000 kbps, microphone OFF`

Recently, I faced a problem with recording process on some Dahua cameras, when I turned the microphone ON.

Normally I use `segment` argument to get 60 s video clips, and when microphone is ON, `speed` parameter grows up to x60 what causes saving clip almost every 1 s. This problem is even stranger as I don't capture audio (`-an` option), and it occurs only on some Dahua models and doesn't show up on other models.

My command is

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i 'rtsp://<USER>:<PASSWORD>@<CAMERA_ADDRESS>' -vcodec copy -an -dn -y -segment_time 60 -strftime 1 -reset_timestamps 1 -f segment %Y-%m-%d-%H-%M.mp4
```

This problem starts in 2-5 minutes since I change camera settings event if the recording process is already running.
The log from ffmpeg when problem shows up is following:

```
frame=  609 fps= 10 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=01:01:01.64 bitrate=N/A speed=  63x
frame=  609 fps= 10 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=01:01:01.64 bitrate=N/A speed=  63x
frame=  625 fps= 10 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=01:01:03.24 bitrate=N/A speed=61.4x
frame=  625 fps= 10 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=01:01:03.24 bitrate=N/A speed=61.4x
frame=  630 fps= 10 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=01:01:03.76 bitrate=N/A speed=60.8x
frame=  630 fps= 10 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=01:01:03.76 bitrate=N/A speed=60.8x
frame=  641 fps= 10 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=01:01:04.85 bitrate=N/A speed=59.8x
frame=  641 fps= 10 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=01:01:04.85 bitrate=N/A speed=59.8x
```

I've tried all audio codecs available for this camera
[image: audio config]

Camera model is Dahua IPC-EW5541-AS. The same problem is on Dahua IPC-HDBW4231F-AS, but IPC-HDW4433C-A works just normal.

I'm trying to understand what can be wrong here, and how to resolve this issue. It would be really useful for me to be able to turn on microphone and record audio stream in parallel (with other script)

Do you have any idea?